# JavaScript Regex newlines ruin bibtex parsing

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I am trying to read a bibtex file into my JavaScript script. 
The Regex used to parse the file is:

```
/(.*)\s*=\s*[{"'](.*|.*\s+.*|.*\s+.*\s+.*|.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*|.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*)[}"'],?/g
```

This works as I want it to:

```
@Article{journals/aim/Sloman99,
  title =   "Review of Affective Computing",
  author =  "Aaron Sloman",
  journal = "AI Magazine",
  year =    "1999",
  number =  "1",
  volume =  "20",
  url = "http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/aim/aim20.html#Sloman99",
  pages =   "127--133",
}
```

It gives me nice key.value pairs like:   "author : Aaron Sloman".

This doesn't:

```
@Article{journals/aim/Sloman99,
  title =   "Review of Affective Computing",
  author =  "Aaron
  S
  l
  o
  m
  a
  n",
  journal = "AI Magazine",
  year =    "1999",
  number =  "1",
  volume =  "20",
  url = "http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/aim/aim20.html#Sloman99",
  pages =   "127--133",
}
```

It just omits the author.

So how can I make a regex that matches an entry with as much newlines (not only as much as there are repetitions of ".*\s+") as there are till it encounters a " or a }?

Comment: you'll need a BIGGER sub-expression than `.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*` to match all the whitespace that the newline incurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know people love to use regular expressions to parse markup, it seems to be a fad... like lady gaga, or the Fun Dip.  But if you want to parse mark up efficentially you should use a parser or write one.

Why,  Regular expressions is meant to parse [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Most markdowns cannot be expressed as an [NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_state_machine) or [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_state_machine). And because of this using regex to parse them is... impossible at the hardest point, and just slow at the easiest.

There are a couple great JS bibtex parsers out there

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsbibtex/
- http://code.google.com/p/bibtex-js/

are two, I recommend you look at those... I know you have already done work to create your regular expression but I promise your job will become much easier when you take the step to a real parser.

Just a small example of why your regex is bad and a parser is better.

Matching patterns include

```
;;;)(>$#@ = 'dfsa3 342 '}
((())))+++>$#@ = 'dfsa3@@//''''''''''''
>$#@ = 'dfsa3@@//'''}}}}"""
```

These are not good!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Austin, but the problem about the two libraries you suggest is that I am not sure if I am legally allowed to use them,
because the software I am writing isn't free software. Also the regex is not my whole program but just the part used to read the tags.
In fact I am trying to write a parser but I am not used to programming in JavaScript, and regex where to first thing that I found to do the job. So any suggestions on how to correct the regex or another simple solution on how to do that are very welcome.

Comment: It tried to use bibtex-js now, but I doesn't work with my input files, because it's comment handling is broken, and I am having troubles fixing it. Also I am still not 100% sure if the MIT License allows me to use it. I am writing an in-house tool to upload publication lists via Greasemonkey so the code will never be published.

Comment: After a small changes Bibtex-js works as I want it too. And I am pretty sure now that what I am doing complies to the MIT License. Thank you.

Comment: MIT License in a nutshell says use it for everything and anything you want without permission. You are safe

Comment: FYI, of anyone came here looking for a BibTeX parser that doesn't take shortcuts, look into my project incidentally also called [bibtex-js](https://github.com/digitalheir/bibtex-js). It parses comments, concatenated strings, etc.